# Why does short-hand assignment not work in my babel setup?

Tags: node.js, babeljs

## Background

I am currently in the process of migrating the backend of my project to ES6 via babel and am running into an error that seems to be related to a short-hand assignment that is not working anymore? I am not familiar with babel. Might be that I am not seeing something super obvious here.

## Problem

now when trying to run my app in dev via `yarn start` I am seeing the following error (simplified example) this did work prior to setting up babel (I am on `node.js 13.13.0`). Any idea what's going on here?

#### Codesnippet:

```
const a = {
  hi:1, bye:2, ciao: 3
}
const b  = {hi, bye} = a
console.log(b)
```

#### Errormessage:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `NODE_ENV=development babel-node server.js server.js`
/Users/user/Projects/fb/fb-flow-app/server/config/config.js:21
var b = (_a = a, hi = _a.hi, bye = _a.bye, _a);
                    ^

ReferenceError: hi is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Projects/fb/fb-flow-app/server/config/config.js:12:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1123:30)
    at Module._compile (/Users/user/Projects/fb/fb-flow-app/server/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/Users/user/Projects/fb/fb-flow-app/server/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:872:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1012:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Projects/fb/fb-flow-app/server/server.js:1:14)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

## High-level project structure:

```
root
|-frontend
|-server
```

The frontend is a `next.js` project and has it's own `.babelrc` which seems to be working.

## Steps taken so far

I've installed a couple of babel-dev-dependencies (in my server folder):

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/node": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.2",
    ...
}
```

and also tried (with no result)

```
@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties
@babel/plugin-transform-spread
```

I've configured my `nodemon.json`:

```
{
    "watch": ["../server"],
    "exec": "NODE_ENV=development babel-node server.js",
    "ext": "js"
}
```

I've set up a `.babelrc`

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

And then I am running via:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently --prefix none \"cd server && NODE_ENV=development yarn nodemon server.js\" \"cd frontend && yarn dev\""
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the following:

```
const a = {
  hi:1, bye:2, ciao: 3
}
const b  = {hi, bye} = a
```

Babel sees an assignment to two variables, named `hi` and `bye` that don't yet exist. It seems that Babel is operating in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) where this is an error. You'll get the same in Node while in strict mode. Solve this by defining them explicitly:

```
const a = {
  hi:1, bye:2, ciao: 3
}
let hi, bye;
const b  = {hi, bye} = a
```

Destructuring does not make an object, despite it *looking* like an object initialization.

Note how, because of that, the value of `b` is *not* an object that looks like `{hi:1, bye:2}` but a reference to `a`, just like what would happen if you just do `const b = a`:

```
const b = a;
a.hi = 5;
console.log(b.hi); // 5
```

Other things you can do:

- `const {hi, bye} = a;` to get two const variables named `hi` and `bye` (rather than `var` or `let`)
- `const {hi: b, bye: c} = a;` to get two variables named `b` and
  `c` ("renaming")
- `const {hi, bye} = a; const b = {hi, bye};` to make an object with just those two keys in variable `b`, but this will also create variables `hi` and `bye`.

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation. Do you understand why it used to work that exact same way before setting up Babel or is there a way to fix Babel to also work with this syntax? I would expect this one https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-shorthand-properties to work, but it seems like it does not.

Comment: I don't have your exact set-up, could you try `let hi, bye; const b = {hi, bye} = a;` ? -- This does seem to work in native node: it both destructures to (implicitly) create variables `hi` and `bye` *and* returns an object into `b`.

Comment: yea `let hi, bye; const b = {hi, bye} = a` and also splitting the statement over two lines works. I am just flabbergasted, that native `node.js` would allow newer JS features than babel (as babel is supposed to transpile down). As I said, first time babel, so I am assuming I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: I'll update my answer to reflect this. I'm not actually sure if Babel is in the wrong here or if Node/V8 is a bit lax in this regard.

Comment: Answer updated — turns out, Node behaves the same in strict mode, which Babel uses by default. Mystery solved!

Comment: Amazing! I assume it is advisable to write code that passes strict mode. Although it seems a bit stupid to use a third-party library to only assign part of an object to another one.

Comment: It's not pretty, but you can do `const b = Object.fromEntries( Object.entries(a).filter( ([key]) => ['hi', 'bye'].includes(key) ) )` to do that.